# moving around uploaded files in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, upload

I need to resize an uploaded image.
The class that resizes needs to get the location of the image to be worked with.
It returns the image in a variable.

However, when I try to get the path to the image, I get from `$_FILES['profile_upload']['tmp_name']` the following: `C:\xampp\tmp\php1C5.tmp`
I **don't** get the actual file, even though the `tmp` folder contains it!

How can I get the actual filename? Another question - for how long are the files stored in `tmp`, and when do they get deleted?

By the way, does the Zend Framework have a good image manipulation interface?

Answer (score 3):

You should complete the whole file upload setup with something similar and then the variable $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] will also contain the original file name:

```
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To address your second point: Files are stored until the script they were uploaded to finishes.